# Which kind of bird is in the picture?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

I am wondering what kind of bird this is. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a male Rufous Whistler ([*Pachycephala rufiventris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufous_whistler)).

> The species is sexually [dimorphic](http://capricorncoastbirds.com/Rufous%20Whistler.html). While females are typically dull brown or grey with streaked underbodies, males are predominantly dark-grey with white throats and (in most cases) a black mask that covers most of their head and some of their neck.

Your picture is from : [hbw.com](http://www.hbw.com/ibc/photo/rufous-whistler-pachycephala-rufiventris/bird-singing-tree).